# Auto Refresh Picture does not work in IE version 9

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, internet-explorer-9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">

</head>

<body>

    <img name="img" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Jdj5JKTA1xQ/T-BzvrQDZhI/AAAAAAAABhs/bX0TUEFb3Ck/s1600/windows-help1.png" width="90%" height="100%">


    <script>
        setInterval(function () {
            var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); // get all img DOM objects
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(/\btime=[^&]*/, 'time=' + new Date().getTime());
            }
        }, 1000);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In Chrome I can see my picture refresh every second, but in IE version 9 it does not work. It does not refresh after displaying one time. How can I solve this problem, or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What is the `1 seconds` at end of your JS code? If you have it in your real code it is an error.

Comment: sorry that 1 just a miss take when i post, it should not have it. thx for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code, as is, should work. Also in IE 9.

Try something like this to verify that the scr attribute actually get changed:

<kbd>***[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/VwXt6/)***</kbd>

JSFiddle does not work well in IE 8 – which I tested on, but this should give you a viewable sample for IE:

<kbd>***[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/VwXt6/embedded/result/)***</kbd>

HTML:

```
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png?time=123" />
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png?time=123" />
<br/>
Img0.src: <input type="text" /><br/>
Img1.src: <input type="text" /><br />
Counter : <input type="text" />
```

CSS:

```
input {
    width : 500px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var cnt = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    inp[2].value = ++cnt;
    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        img[i].src = img[i].src
            .replace(/\btime=[^&]*/, 'time=' + new Date().getTime());
        inp[i].value = img[i].src;
    }
}, 1000);
```